# Ubuntu 14.04 Login Loop after installing new GPU

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, login

I've looked everywhere and tried seemingly everything, I am not able to log into my ubuntu partition.  It loads, opens up the login screen, and I can type in my password, but when I enter it it freezes for a second, then glitches out and resets to the login screen.  I've tried many things, but at this point I need more in depth help than looking at previous people's problems with a google search.

This error started occurring after I installed my new GTX 1070, so it has something to do with that.  Don't hesitate to throw out ideas, because there has got to be some out there that actually work

Answer (score 1):

On the logon screen, open tty1 by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>.

Logon with your username and password.

Then run this command:

```
sudo rm .Xauthority
sudo reboot
```

Then try logging in. If it works, great!

If not, try purging the Nvidia drivers and them rum the above commands again.